# Override custom look and feel with system default minimize, maximize, and close buttons

Tags: java, swing, button, system

Is it possible to get the default system icons for the close, minimize/maximize, and restore down buttons in the titlebar? I am using a custom look and feel from jtattoo but I would rather use the system titlebar icons.  I have tried this but the width and height have negative values and the buttons are empty.

```
Icon closeIcon = UIManager.getIcon("InternalFrame.closeIcon");
SmartLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(props);            
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.smart.SmartLookAndFeel");
UIManager.put("InternalFrame.closeIcon", closeIcon);
```

Comment: Not really.  You'd most likely need a JNI/JNA based solution and even then, it's not likely to work